# Get file in specific folder that contains a specific string of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, scripting, contains

I am using javascript to handle the images on my local only website. I am trying to get the image that contains a specific character in a specified folder. For example, if there is an image named "run0.jpg", I want to be able to return the path to the image by searching the folder for files with jpg extensions that contain the character "0". I've tried a few things with no success.

Does anyone know of any javascript tricks that could help me get this accomplished? Thanks, any insight is appreciated

Comment: Not possible. Javascript runs in the browser, you can't go poking around the local file system.

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly , at "local only website" , i.e.g., `file://` protocol, or `localhost` , attempting to search local folder and return "path" to image having a specific character within the file name ?

Try

```
// array of character to search for
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
// results
, res = [];
// request variations of file name,
// utilizing `arr` characters 
$.each(arr, function(value, i) {
  $.ajax("file:///path/to/local/folder/run" + value + ".jpg")
  .then(function(data, textStatus) {
    // if request successful, push `url`, or "path", to `res`
    res.push(this.url);
  })
});

console.log(res);
```

To utilize `file://` protocol , at chrome / chromiumn , see [How do I make the Google Chrome flag “--allow-file-access-from-files” permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/192996#192996) ; at `localhost` , see [Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)